# shrinkwrap deforms mesh

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I am trying to wrap one mesh around/against another, First I wrap it around with "simple deform" modifier, then shrinkwrap it; however, the Shrinkwrap deforms the mesh. How can I wrap it, without it being deformed?
[edit] .blend http://www.pasteall.org/blend/34302

[image][image][image]

Comment: did you try the other modes of this modifier " Project "

Comment: yes, it turns into a jumbled mess http://i.imgur.com/gWxy0Yg.png

Comment: check positive, negative, X, Y and resize the mesh and see if you get something better !

Comment: tried several combos with no success, I uploaded the .blend if you want to try something.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- first use the simple mesh  "before applying the solidify modifier " because it will be flattened when you apply the shrinkwrap
- add the **shrinkwrap** modifier with these settings

[image]

- select the target and hit  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and apply object transform

[image]

Comment: Try to make the wrapped object as close as possible to the other object, this will make it better. Order of modifiers : simple deform, shrinkwrap, solidify.