# How to use the shrinkwrap modifier with the shrunk mesh remaining unchanged?

Tags: modeling, shrinkwrap

I'm trying to shrinkwrap a pattern mesh to a tire mesh, but the result always has some kind of deformation. I've checked out this similar question on this site: [shrinkwrap deforms mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24528/shrinkwrap-deforms-mesh), but applying scales does no help at all. I've pushed the subdivision surface modifier to 4 level on the tire mesh, but the deformation still persists.

Is this true that there's no escape from deformation when using shrinkwrap modifiers?

[image: Paterrn mesh]

[image: Deformation]

My Blender file: [Tires.blend](https://gofile.io/?c=Rq9IVh).

Thank you for your time!

Comment: I think the problem come from 3 vertices. There are located just above the "pick" on the pattern mesh (starting from the lower vertex, on the left in front view). They cause problem with solidify. But I don't know what are your constraints about the pattern, so I can't correct it.

Comment: There is five vertices in fact, some are nearly doubled.

Comment: Thank you Lemon! But is it the only source of problem? I'll revisit the mesh tomorrow, but I'm afraid the mesh still deforms a little bit. Is there any way to ensure that the pattern remains exactly the same when using shrinkwrap?

Comment: After this correction, that seem to be ok. But "exactly the same is not possible here, in particular due to the curve that will modify the alignements.

Comment: So this isn't the optimal way to make a tire with difficult pattern? The way I see it, the pattern on the real tire is very crisp; it doesn't look defective at all. How can you make such a tire?

Comment: I don't know, this mainly depend on what you want to achieve (and always difficult to affirm the 'most optimal' way). I'll try to look at it a bit more.

Comment: @lemon: Hi friend, I've found the solution to our problem, which is fully demonstrated in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PcIu2hIO4Og. I find this method much more robust than the shrinkwrap technique when it comes to modeling tires.

Comment: thank you for the tip! Will look at it.